# Google prevents send mail from subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail

I have a php-codeigniter project on a live server. When I run scripts to send mail via gmail on my domain, it runs successfully, but on my subdomain with same code , google throws error as below:

```
    220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a27-v6sm1183622pfc.18 - gsmtp
hello: 501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "~^(?.+)\.domain\.com$" invalid,
501-5.5.4 closing connection.
501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo a27-v6sm1183622pfc.18 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "~^(?.+)\.domain\.com$" invalid,
501-5.5.4 closing connection.
501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo a27-v6sm1183622pfc.18 - gsmtp
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 04:26:50 -0400
From: "My Project" <domain@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <domain@gmail.com>
To: trantuanlinh193@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Test?=
Reply-To: <domain@gmail.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: domain@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5b1f83caaac1a@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a test email
```

What can I do now?

Comment: where's the code

Answer (score 0):

Google's explaination to this type of error:

> The HELO/EHLO error means that the mail server sending to Google has identified itself with an invalid value.
>
> When mail servers talk to each other, they're required to identify themselves to the receiving server via a HELO or EHLO command.  This identification should be the sending machine's fully-qualified domain name (like mail.example.com), or, if that’s not available, its IP address.  Any other value is considered invalid and may cause your email to be rejected.

Apparently, it seems that there is something missing or the info is incomplete, that you are sending to google's servers.

Check this [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6386757) for more info